# Why is my background music not looping?

Tags: c#, loops, xna, audio

Dose anyone have any idae why this code is not working for my background music to constantly loop??

In load Content:

```
backgroundMusic.Play(0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //play background music (first float number is for volume)
```

In update:

```
SoundEffectInstance instance = backgroundMusic.CreateInstance(); //creates instance for backgroundMusic
instance.IsLooped = true; //states that instance should loop meaning background music loops and never stops
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: I now have this:

Content Load:

```
        Song backgroundMusic = Content.Load<Song>("backgroundMusic");
```

and then seperately:

```
    public void PlayMusicRepeat(Song backgroundMusic)
    {

        MediaPlayer.Play(backgroundMusic);
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to manage the backgroud music you should use the `Song` class, `SoundEffect` should be used only for sound effects.
Something like this:

```
public void PlayMusicRepeat(Song song)
{
    MediaPlayer.Play(song);
    MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
}
```

Of course the loading should be like this:

```
Song music = Game.Content.Load<Song>("background");
```

Comment: Please see code edit above, am I right in thinking you mean something like this?

Comment: No. You are still using `SoundEffect` and `SoundEffectInstance`, but if you want to manage the music you should use the `Song` class.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the answer properly. Have once again edited it.

Comment: You are doing `SoundEffectInstance instance = backgroundMusic.CreateInstance();`, this assumes that `backgroundMusic` is a `SoundEffect`, so how can it be a `Song` too?

Comment: Please check my updated code, does this look like it should work to you? I'm now getting no audio output at all?

Comment: I hope you are loading the right audio file, and its extension must be .mp3 to work. Now to play the song you need to call that method.

Answer (score 1):

You are playing the SoundEffect, but looping the SoundEffectInstance, that won't work.
And following this article from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940203.aspx), you have to set the IsLooped property BEFORE playing the sound.

So your code should look like this:

In LoadContent:

```
instance = backgroundMusic.CreateInstance(); 
instance.IsLooped = true;
```

In Update:

```
if(instance.State == SoundState.Stopped)
    instance.Play();
```